# mapbox mapID not working?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've just started looking at mapbox, and I've run into an issue straight away.

I've copied the sample here;
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/

Please note this part;

```
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken =     'pk.eyJ1IjoibWF1cmljZXdhbG1zbGV5IiwiYSI6ImNpbmxiZjc4djB5cjJ0dG0zejZjZHZxdjEifQ.CJHrqKevqria7ZbVMOMD5Q';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
.setView([40, -74.50], 9);
</script>
```

Un-editted it works in my webpage.
If I change the accessToken to my one, it works.
If I then change the mapID, though, from "mapbox.streets" to "myusername.mapID" (I've double checked these, they are correct) all I get is an empty map.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for — [Add styles made with Mapbox Studio using styleLayer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/stylelayer/)

Also, Check your Browsers console.  In Firefox, I got the following error in the console

```
Error: Styles created with Mapbox Studio need to be 
used with L.mapbox.styleLayer, not L.mapbox.tileLayer
```

Comment: Can't upvote enough. Man was that hard to track down in their docs!